# Why does my express POST endpoint return 404 when Content-Type is set by requester?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express server:

```
import express from "express";

const app = express()
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json()) 

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  next();
});

app.post(/city\/get-ids/g, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port);
```

as well as a front end fetch request:

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/city/get-ids/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({a: 1})
});
```

If I comment out `Content-Type` on the fetch, I get a "Hello World" response, but the server logs req.body as being an empty object.

If I keep the `Content-Type` on fetch, I get a 404.

---

**Why does setting Content-Type make express return a 404 while not setting it returns "Hello World"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in an issue, got a better response (https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4590)

The problem was the global `g` in `app.post(/city\/get-ids/g`.

You can see more about why here: [Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results)

Anyways, the solution is to just remove the `g`:

```
app.post(/city\/get-ids/, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('Hello World!')
});
```

---

**Old post for comment posterity:**

Alright.  Fixed it, but it still makes absolutely zero sense.

Here's the fix:

```
app.post("/city/get-ids*", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

For some reason the RegExp version just doesn't work if Content-Type is set.  The OPTIONS preflight returns correctly either way.  If there's no Content-Type the POST route matches correctly.  But RegExp for POST routes no longer works when Content-Type is set.

It makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: It sounds like a bug with Express, perhaps [create an issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues)?

Comment: Holy hell, that's one tasty gotcha! Just a note that if you're going to stick with a regex, you may want to anchor the pattern with `^` and `$`, as per [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#boundary-type_assertions). Otherwise you might get caught out by stuff like this:
`/city\/get-ids/g.test('/foo/city/get-ids/bar/') === true`